# Is it acceptable to use "followed by" in this way?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

"in 1995, the lowest proportion of money was spent on drugs at 3%, **followed by** transport and communication, at 5%, which was half the percentage spent on education and research (10%)."

I used "followed by" to introduced the second lowest proportion, and I am not sure whether English rules allows this. From my experience, "followed by" is used to introduce the second highest or commonest thing; for example, "the largest proportion of money was used to buy food, at 49%, followed by clothes, at 45%, and books, at 34%."

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's correct.

If you happen to use a word that specifies the lower end of a range, it is assumed that the things that follow it get bigger. If you use a word that specifies the higher, things that follow get smaller.